# How do I add the "onload" attribute to a script tag?

Tags: 7, forms

I need to add the onload event in jquery script tag as advagg does. I have done a bit of research, and I found that they are actually invoking `hook_element_info_alter()` and thereby add their `hook_advagg_modify_js_pre_render()` implementation into it. Then, they alter the child elements.

When I do the same in a `hook_element_info_alter()` implementation, `type['script']` is not there.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the reason you can't use drupal behviours for the onload events? https://sqndr.github.io/d8-theming-guide/javascript/behaviors.html

Comment: I want add the onload event only to jquery library and the drupal js asbecause if I add the defer attribute to them or move them to footer the whole page got collapsed

Comment: Assuming you're using Drupal 8, And your page is collapsing, so I think it is about a theme. you should then declare your script in libraries as head. I'll try to explain it in the answser

Comment: Sorry I am using drupal 7 . Is there any way I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure you're javascript is loaded in the header:

**For drupal 7**

`/sites/default/themes/yourtheme/template.php`

```
function theme_preprocess_html(&$var) {
      $path = $GLOBALS['base_url'] . '/' . path_to_theme() . '/js/yourscript-min.js';
      $script = array(
        '#tag' => 'script',
        '#attributes' => array(
            'type' => 'text/javascript',
            'src' => $path
        ),
        '#value' => '',
       );
       drupal_add_html_head($script, 'script');  
    }
```

or if you want it loaded in the page:

```
function theme_preprocess_html(&$var) {
      $script = array(
        '#tag' => 'script',
        '#attributes' => array('type' => 'text/javascript'),
        '#value' => 'Add your javascript here',
       );
       drupal_add_html_head($script, 'script');  
    }
```

**For drupal 8**

In the yourtheme.libraries.yml you need to create a library like so:

`yourtheme.libraries.yml`

```
library-name:
  header: true
  js:
    js/yourSrctipForTheHeader.js: {}
```

Also in the `theme.info.yml` you need to add this library, then it will automatically comes in head tag and will be available before the page load, if you remove `header:true` the script will be loaded after the page load.

`theme.info.yml`

```
libraries:
  - yourtheme/library-name
```

Alternativly, you can make use of this module: 
https://www.drupal.org/project/header_and_footer_scripts and put the scipts in manually in the position that you want. But to be honest, i think the first solution is the more elegant way.

Comment: Thanks fro your suggestion . I am using drupal 7

Comment: I've updated the answer for drupal 7

Comment: Sorry I did not asked , that , My Question is how to override hook_advagg_modify_js_pre_render like advagg does and how they implemented advagg_get_js